# How can a previously removed component be fully restored from standard values?

Tags: content-editor, presentation, templates, components, experience-editor

When a component coming from a template has been removed from a page item, it can be restored by resetting layouts from standard values.  However, if changes are made to the component at the template level those changes are not reflected in the component within the reset page.  Is there a way of fully restoring that component without rebuilding the page from scratch?  For example:

### Template final layout:

TemplateLevelComponentA
TemplateLevelComponentB
TemplateLevelComponentC

### Page final layout:

TemplateLevelComponentA
TemplateLevelComponentB
***TemplateLevelComponentC is removed***

### Page final layout--reset from standard values:

TemplateLevelComponentA
TemplateLevelComponentB
TemplateLevelComponentC--appears to have been restored

### Template final layout:

TemplateLevelComponentA
TemplateLevelComponentB
TemplateLevelComponentC--change made to placeholder or data source

### Page final layout--previously reset from standard values:

TemplateLevelComponentA
TemplateLevelComponentB
TemplateLevelComponentC--matches state of component on template at time of reset, has not received change made to placeholder or data source

Have tried resetting just final layout from standard values, have tried final and shared, have tried field reset--none of them restore the component so that it receives subsequent changes made at the template level.  Other pages where the component was not removed are receiving the changes.

Comment: Is the 3 renderings also available on the Share or is it only on the Final layout?

Comment: Hishaam coming to the rescue again!  Thanks!  The 3 components are only on the final layout.

Comment: For final layouts, the value can either be a patch XML or a full layout XML. In your case it appears to be a patch XML on Page items final renderings field when you removed the component. You can read this for more info: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/versioned-layouts.html